# Computer Boots Straight into Windows (Dual-Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I’ve just installed Ubuntu 18.04 from a live Disc. When prompted to ‘remove installation medium and press Enter’ it restarted and now boots into Windows 10 every time. My computer uses UEFI, both Windows and Ubuntu are installed there. There is no option to move Grub up in boot order in my UEFI settings as it is not even listed. I have no way to access Ubuntu and I’m unsure if using my live disc again will cause any problems, as, of course, I already have Ubuntu installed.

I know there are many similar questions like this but they never seem to have a clear answer or just don’t resolve my problem.

I’d appreciate it if anybody could help!

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: _I know there are many similar questions like this but they never seem to have a clear answer or just don’t resolve my problem_ Which articles, specifically, did you try and find wanting, so we can rules those out? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @Justin Cunningham Need to look at your partitions. Run `sudo parted -l` from Live Ubuntu and post output into question.

Answer (score 0):

okay first of all you should enter the advanced startup options menu like this **(without the boot flash is inserted)** 
 [image]

after you should get this screen and from this screen choose **use a device**
[image]
from there you should see the ubuntu partition

**also another way**
you can try to set grub in front of windows with this command

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```